# Azure quantum error message

Tags: qiskit, programming, ionq, azure-quantum

I am using the IonQ QPU on the Azure quantum provider with a [Google Cloud API](https://ionq.com/docs/get-started-with-google-cloud) to access the [native gates](https://ionq.com/docs/getting-started-with-native-gates). As you can see in the image attached, I got this error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(107, 'Transport endpoint is not connected'))
```

[image: OSError107]

**What could be the reason for this error?**

Comment: Which error comes first, the `OSError` or the `ConnectionError`?

Comment: The OSerror comes first.